# CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR- JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

Hey have someone had this with next-auth, I am trying to make my login authentication with next-auth but it keeps giving me this error and after submit the form it redirects me to `/api/auth/error`.

my .env has `NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET` and `NEXTAUTH_URL`

Before submit the form the console shows these errors:
[image: Console error Login Page]

My […nextauth] code:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

import User from '../../utils/user';
import dbConnect from '../../lib/dbConnect';

export default NextAuth({
  // Enable JSON Web Tokens since we will not store sessions in our DB
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  // Here we add our login providers - this is where you could add Google or Github SSO as well
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: 'credentials',
      // The credentials object is what's used to generate Next Auths default login page - We will not use it however.
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      // Authorize callback is ran upon calling the signin function
      authorize: async (credentials, req) => {
        dbConnect();

        // Try to find the user and also return the password field
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).select(
          '+password'
        );

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('No user with a matching email was found.');
        }

        // Use the comparePassword method we defined in our user.js Model file to authenticate
        const pwValid = await user.comparePassword(credentials.password);

        if (!pwValid) {
          throw new Error('Your password is invalid');
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],

  // All of this is just to add user information to be accessible for our app in the token/session
  callbacks: {
    // We can pass in additional information from the user document MongoDB returns
    // This could be avatars, role, display name, etc...
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = {
          _id: user._id,
          email: user.email,
          role: user.role,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
    // If we want to access our extra user info from sessions we have to pass it the token here to get them in sync:
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.user = token.user;
      }
      console.log(session);
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    // Here you can define your own custom pages for login, recover password, etc.
    signIn: '/login', // we are going to use a custom login page (we'll create this in just a second)
  },
});
```

following my Login page code:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { Box, Button, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';

const initialValues = {
  name: '',
  password: '',
};

const userSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required('This is required'),
  password: yup.string().required('This is required'),
});

// This goes to our signup API endpoint
async function createUser(email, password) {
  const response = await fetch('/api/signup', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || 'Something went wrong!');
  }

  return data;
}

// This gets handled by the [...nextauth] endpoint
function AuthForm() {
  const [registered, setRegistered] = useState(false);
  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();

  // We keep track of whether in a login / or register state
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();

  function switchAuthModeHandler() {
    setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState);
  }

  const submitHandler = async (values, { resetForm }) => {
    resetForm();

    const enteredEmail = values.name;
    const enteredPassword = values.password;

    // optional: Add validation here

    if (isLogin) {
      await signIn('credentials', {
        email: enteredEmail,
        password: enteredPassword,
        redirect: false,
      });
    } else {
      try {
        const result = await createUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
        setRegistered(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    resetForm();
  };

  return (
    <section className="max-w-xl mx-auto my-7">
      {!registered ? (
        <>
          <h1>{isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Sign Up'}</h1>
          <Box m="20px">
            <Formik
              onSubmit={submitHandler}
              initialValues={initialValues}
              validationSchema={userSchema}
            >
              {({
                values,
                errors,
                touched,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
              }) => {
                return (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Box
                      display="grid"
                      gap="30px"
                      gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
                    >
                      <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        variant="filled"
                        type="text"
                        label="Name"
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.name}
                        name="name"
                        error={!!touched.name && !!errors.name}
                        helperText={touched.firstName && errors.name}
                        sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                      />

                      <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        variant="filled"
                        type="password"
                        label="password"
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={values.password}
                        name="password"
                        error={!!touched.password && !!errors.password}
                        helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                        sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                      />
                    </Box>
                    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="end" mt="20px">
                      <Button
                        type="submit"
                        color="secondary"
                        variant="contained"
                      >
                        {isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Create Account'}
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        onClick={switchAuthModeHandler}
                        type="button"
                        color="secondary"
                        variant="contained"
                      >
                        {isLogin
                          ? 'No Account? Create One'
                          : 'Already a user? Login'}
                      </Button>
                    </Box>
                  </form>
                );
              }}
            </Formik>
          </Box>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="">
          <p>You have successfully registered!</p>

          <button
            onClick={() => router.reload()}
            className="button button-color"
          >
            Login Now
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

export default AuthForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it moving the [...nextauth].js to the /api/auth/ , it was only inside the API folder before

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This same JSON error happened for me, but it was due to my MongoDB Atlas not having access from the general internet, just my development IP. Once I added that it then began to work.